# String Vumark is recognized as hex

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

On developer portal i created new VuMark database with tupe string and created my vumark template.
Then make example images like on
[image: image 1].

Then in Unity switch database to my (tried in example and in my project) and its showing that is string in unity when loooking into it -
[image: image 2]

and when run app and tried to scan Vumark it is readed as hex (in debug in script it has type set to hex) and in example app it show value like 0x000......

Any ideas what is wrong?

I also created thred on Vuforia forum - [link](https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/images/string-vumark-recognized-hex)

Some similar threads is on forums but always abbadoned without resolution.

Comment: Did u get a solution?

Comment: Nope i switch to ar foundation with qr foundation asset